# Is there a difference between "|" and "¦" when it comes to scripting?

Tags: scripting, pipe

For instance, when outputting the results of process A into process B by piping, can either "|" or "¦" be used? A|B , A¦B ?

Comment: That very much depends on the language in question and what it recognizes as the pipe operator.

Comment: It would appear to be shell-dependent. In Bash ¦ seems to be treated as a normal character and serves no purpose.

Comment: ¦ *Ceci n'est pas une pipe.*